# Show only One Component on a Route and Hide All Others

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I am Making an App it has a Side Bar which I am showing in all routes.
I want to hide everything on Login and Register Routes and only show Login and Register forms.
How can I achieve it?

Here's is how I have structured it out

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <BodyContainer>
        <SideBar />
        <div>
         <Header/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path="/create" component={NewInvoice} />
            <Route exact path="/invoices" component={Invoices} />
            <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />
            <Route exact path="/invoice/:id" component={InvoiceDetails} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BodyContainer>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

I want to hide everything inside `BodyContainer` and Show a new Login Page.

Comment: Do you want to restrict access to routes in react-router before login and register? or just hide them in sidebar ?

Comment: No, I was not talking about Route Protection. I want to Hide Everything and show Login form on `/login` Route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply handle it before rendering the main page 
like this code

```
render(){
    const isUserLoggedIn = false;
    const privateRoutes = 
    (   <>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path="/create" component={NewInvoice} />
            <Route exact path="/invoices" component={Invoices} />
            <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />
            <Route exact path="/invoice/:id" component={InvoiceDetails} />
        </>
    );
    const publicRoutes = (
        <>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Redirect to="/"/>
            <
        </>
    );

    const content = isUserLoggedIn ? privateRoutes : publicRoutes;

    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <BodyContainer>
                <SideBar />
                <div>
                <Header/>
                    {content}
                </div>
            </BodyContainer>
        </BrowserRouter>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the pathname to decide whether or not to render:

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <BodyContainer>
        {
          ['/login', '/register'].indexOf(window.location.pathname) == -1 && <SideBar />
        }
        <div>
         <Header/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path="/create" component={NewInvoice} />
            <Route exact path="/invoices" component={Invoices} />
            <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />
            <Route exact path="/invoice/:id" component={InvoiceDetails} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BodyContainer>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Another solution is to restructure your components such that the SideBar is included inside each component, which would give you the flexibility of choosing which components should show it.